# Bug in \SetProgSty command in algorithm2e package

Tags: algorithm2e, bugs

I found a bug in the `\SetProgSty` command. Currently, it incorrectly sets the `\ArgSty` command instead of `\ProgSty`:

```
\newcommand{\SetProgSty}[1]{\renewcommand{\ArgSty}[1]{\textnormal{\csname#1\endcsname{##1}}\unskip}}%
```

It's possible to get around this bug by patching the command using etoolbox:

```
\patchcmd{\SetProgSty}{ArgSty}{ProgSty}{}{}
```

but I think this should be fixed in the next release.

I tried emailing the package author but the address given in the manual no longer works. Subscribing to the mailing list also does not seem to work. The author does seem to be active here, though.

Also, the documentation mentions the existence of a `\SetProgArgFnt` command, but in the implementation there is no such command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report. You are the first to notice this bug, perhaps are you the only one that wants to change the ProgSty! But again, thanks for the report.

I have changed it for the next release.

Strange that I didn't receive neither you email, nor the mailing list subscription as it is working...

Comment: I sent it to `cfiorio@umontpellier.fr`, which bounced with the error message "Address rejected". Regarding the mailing list, I put the registration string in the body. Perhaps it should have been placed in the subject instead (although the manual said to place it in the body)?